# Why can variable names use $?

Tags: c++, variables

Such as:

```
int $a = 1;
int $$a = 2;
```

Why is this allowed?

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Do have cases where you think it should not have been allowed?

Comment: In the future, please follow this guideline: The title should be short and descriptive, but it shouldn't be the question. Try to formulate complete sentences.

Answer (score 3):

From C++ Standard, 2.11 Identifiers:

```
identifier:
    identifier-nondigit
    identifier identifier-nondigit
    identifier digit 
identifier-nondigit:
    nondigit
    universal-character-name
    other implementation-defined characters
```

See the last line which explicitly allows the implementation to have implementation-defined nondigit characters in an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

There's no special meaning for `$` (like bash/Perl for example) in C++ and there's a no restriction from the C++ standard. `$` is just like any other identifier. But it would look awkward to have `int $;`

Comment: Well, it's special in that the C++ standard doesn't guarantee that using names containing `$` won't result in an ill-formed program.